# Populate form field from form on previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've have HTML code from Listrak to display a form on my site. In Listrak, I've asked this form to redirect to a new page on Submit, where there is a second Listrak form. How can I use Javascript or jQuery to auto-populate the email field from Form 1 to Form 2?

**Form 1:**

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="email" size="40" maxlength="100" id="email" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="name" size="40" maxlength="100" id="name" value=""/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Form 2:**

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="form2">
<input type="text" name="email" size="40" maxlength="100" id="email" value="auto.populated.from.form1"/>
<input type="text" name="hobbies" size="40" maxlength="100" id="hobbies" value=""/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit my question to make it a bit clearer...

Comment: and what's the real question ? is there any problem ?

Comment: What would my script look like? I've found solutions for this elsewhere when two forms are on the same page, but I'm not having any luck using those solutions with form 2 on a new page.

Comment: Using jQuery you can't, you would have to use a server-side language if they are on separate pages. Or I guess you could use cookies.